# Android-Studio : Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine, i can't test my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have intalled android studio for a while, but today i get  this issue that is :  when i want to test my app that is worked well before i get this error message , and i tried a lot of things to resolve this problem but no result

[image]

i try reinstall jdk and install the lateset version but nothing happened 
i try add this things in system variable environment like _JAVA_HOME and Xmx512M also nothing happened and the probelm still there.

could you please help me guys ...

my system description : win 8.1 , cpu=i5 , Ram = 12 gb

Comment: Have you properly instal java in your system

Answer (score 1):

I think you have set a large heap size for your virtual machine and are trying to run it on java 32 bits. If this is the case, try creating a virtual machine with a small heap size 1gb or even 0.5gb and it should work.

Comment: hey friend if you mean this dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
already i changed it to 1g and 0.5g but it didn't work and the problem is still there ...